# how can I quote a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know how to explanation my issue,here is code and error:

```
html_title = 'abc'
file_name = html_title, '.txt'
html_write_to_file = open(file_name, 'wt')
...
...
...
```

error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

I notice that `file_name` must add quotation marks like this

`html_write_to_file = open('file_name', 'wt')`

when I add quotation marks,the Variable functions does not work in `open('file_name', 'wt')`

but I have to use filename format like this:`html_title, '.txt'`

I don't know how to do...

Supplementary question:

characters are Japanese or Chinese,I tried encode to utf-8,still not work well.

Comment: `file_name = html_title, '.txt'` produces a tuple, not one string.

Comment: Your question needs to be "how can I concatenate strings?"

Comment: `"a", "b"` is a `tuple` `("a","b")`, `"a" + "b"` is a `str` `"ab"`. **Comma makes a tuple, not parens.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a *tuple* here:

```
file_name = html_title, '.txt'
```

The comma makes it a tuple; here you created a tuple with two elements. You then pass that tuple to the `open()` command:

```
html_write_to_file = open(file_name, 'wt')
```

which complains that it can only take a string; it tells you that a tuple is not acceptable.

You probably just wanted to add `.txt` to the `html_title` string, so use `+` to concatenate the strings:

```
file_name = html_title + '.txt'
```

Now `file_name` is a string object too.